# Included SQL fragment doesn't substitute parameter

Tags: mybatis, ibatis

My mapper interface looks like this.

```java
public interface CommonMapper {
    long selectSequenceNumber(String sequenceName);
}
```

And I prepared sql mapper looks like this.

```xml
<sql id="sequenceNumber">
  <choose>
    <when test="_databaseId == 'derby'">
      VALUES NEXT VALUE FOR #{sequenceName}
    </when>
    <otherwise>
      SELECT #{sequenceName}.NEXTVAL FROM DUAL
    </otherwise>
  </choose>
</sql>
<select id="selectSequenceNumber" resultType="_long">
  <!--<include refid="....mapper.CommonMapper.sequenceNumber"/>-->
  <include refid="sequenceNumber"/>
</select>
```

When I test mapper `#{sequenceName}` part is not substituted with given.

```
14:36:09.492 [main] DEBUG ....selectSequenceNumber - ==>  Preparing: VALUES NEXT VALUE FOR ? 
14:36:09.724 [main] ERROR ....PersistenceTests - failed to apply function for SqlSession
org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.PersistenceException: 
### Error querying database.  Cause: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax error: Encountered "?" at line 1, column 23.
### The error may exist in .../CommonMapper.xml
### The error may involve ....CommonMapper.selectSequenceNumber
### The error occurred while executing a query
### SQL: VALUES NEXT VALUE FOR ?
### Cause: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax error: Encountered "?" at line 1, column 23.
```

Is this normal? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use string substitution `${sequenceName}` instead of setting the parameter with `#{}` for direct string placement in your queries (such as for giving object names, dynamic sql etc...)

```
<sql id="sequenceNumber">
  <choose>
    <when test="_databaseId == 'derby'">
      VALUES NEXT VALUE FOR ${sequenceName}
    </when>
    <otherwise>
      SELECT ${sequenceName}.NEXTVAL FROM DUAL
    </otherwise>
  </choose>
</sql>
<select id="selectSequenceNumber" resultType="_long">
  <!--<include refid="....mapper.CommonMapper.sequenceNumber"/>-->
  <include refid="sequenceNumber"/>
</select>
```

Comment: Can I actually use `_databaseId` other than `<selectKey/>` I got another error `Parameter '_databaseId' not found`.

Comment: Far as I know, you can use `_databaseId` in any XML, if it's a global parameter and if you are able to write it in a `<selectKey/>`.

Comment: Beware that using ${} syntax might render your application vulnerable to SQL injection (if the input comes from untrusted source).